# Rewrite array based on child array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array of array like

```
{
  "campaigns": [{
      "name": "1st Campaign",
      "books": [{
          "title": "1st book",
          "primary_isbn": "isbn1"
        },
        {
          "title": "2nd book",
          "primary_isbn": "isbn2"
        },
        {
          "title": "3rd book",
          "primary_isbn": "isbn3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "2nd cam",
      "books": [{
          "title": "4th book",
          "primary_isbn": "isbn4"
        },
        {
          "title": "5th book",
          "primary_isbn": "isbn5"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

From above array i need to create new array where each campaign (parent) data converted to number of items per book. So for first item
1st campaign should be converted to 3 items as there are 3 books. so my new array should be

```
{
  "campaigns": [{
      "name": "1st campaign"
      "title": "1st book",
      "primary_isbn": "isbn1"
    },
    {
      "name": "1st campaign"
      "title": "2nd book",
      "primary_isbn": "isbn2"
    },
    {
      "name": "1st campaign"
      "title": "3rd book",
      "primary_isbn": "isbn3"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

And same structure for 2nd campaign.
I am not sure how to approach this problem

I tried this using lodash

```
_.flattenDeep(data.campaigns.books)
```

Comment: Do you have any attempts? Like finding books, campaigns etc.

Comment: what about map function??

Comment: jvm, you need to add in any code you've attempted to your question as [mcve]s. It will likely use a loop of some kind, and access arrays/objects on each iteration to access the information.

Comment: I did try using lodash using _.flattenDeep(data.campaigns.books but that isn't helping

Comment: Where does `"1st book"`, `"2nd book"` in the output come from? Or should that be computed based on the index? Why is `primary_isbn` different from the input?

Comment: Need is just create new array where number of elements determined by child (books) number of items and parent property "name" get duplicated. So new array will contain 5 items instead of 2 (original)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatmap) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like this:

```js
const input = {campaigns:[{name:"1st Campaign",books:[{title:"1st book",primary_isbn:"isbn1"},{title:"2nd book",primary_isbn:"isbn2"},{title:"3rd book",primary_isbn:"isbn3"}]},{name:"2nd cam",books:[{title:"4th book",primary_isbn:"isbn4"},{title:"5th book",primary_isbn:"isbn5"}]}]};

const campaigns = 
  input.campaigns.flatMap(({ name, books }) => books.map(b => ({ ...b, name })))

console.log({ campaigns })
```