# How to flatten an array of objects containing arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I want to flatten the items an array of objects and receive a new result array. How can I achieve it?

This approach did not work:

```js
const group = [{
    idGroup: 1,
    member: [{
      name: "Tim"
    }, {
      name: "Sina"
    }]
  }],
}];

const result = [{
    idGroup: 1,
    name: "Tim"
  },
  {
    idGroup: 1,
    name: "Sina"
  },
]



const result = group.reduce((r, obj) => r.concat(obj.member), []);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It gives a syntax error, please fix

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rewrite array based on child array javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761934/rewrite-array-based-on-child-array-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use `map` too (to make the new items):

```js
const group = [{idGroup:1,member:[{name: "Tim"},{name: "Sina"}]}];
const result = group.reduce((acc, { idGroup, member }) => acc.concat(member.map(({ ...props }) => ({ ...props, idGroup }), [])), []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could map nested objects.

```js
const
    group = [{ idGroup:1, member: [{ name: "Tim" }, { name: "Sina" }] }];
    result = group.reduce(
        (r, { idGroup, member }) => [...r, ...member.map(({ name }) => ({ idGroup, name }))],
        []
    );

console.log(result);
```

Or use upcoming [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).

```js
const
    group = [{ idGroup:1, member: [{ name: "Tim" }, { name: "Sina" }] }];
    result = group.flatMap(({ idGroup, member }) =>
        member.map(({ name }) => ({ idGroup, name })));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flatMap()` and use `map()` on `member` array of object.

```js
const group = [
 {
  idGroup:1,
  member: [{name: "Tim"}, {name: "Sina"}],
 }
];

const res = group.flatMap(x => x.member.map(a => ({...a,idGroup:x.idGroup})));
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) like this:

```js
const group = [{
  idGroup: 1,
  member: [{name: "Tim"}, {name: "Sina"}],
}, {
  idGroup: 2,
  member: [{name: "Jo"}, {name: "Eric"}]
}];

const result = group.reduce((acc, { idGroup, member }) => {
  member.forEach(({ name }) => acc.push({ idGroup, name }));
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

A *good old loop* can work too.

```js
const group =
[{
    idGroup: 1,
    member: [{
      name: "Tim"
    }, {
      name: "Sina"
    }]
},
{
    idGroup: 2,
    member: [{
      name: "foo"
    }, {
      name: "bar"
    }, {
      name: "42"
    }]
}];

let result = [];

group.forEach((elem) => {
  elem.member.forEach((subElem) => {
    result.push({ idGroup: elem.idGroup, name: subElem.name });
  });
});

console.log(result);
```